# Responsive Image List in Rendering Variants

Tags: sxa

**Background :**
I am using SXA 1.9 and Sitecore 9.2 to learn SXA. I am following youtube videos on **SXA Rendering Variants** by Short, ad-hoc, unofficial Sitecore SXA channel.
On the blogs template, there is a multilist field for authors and on authors template, there is a multilist field for reference media.

**Question :**
While creating rendering variants as mentioned in above channel, I have used reference variant(for reference media field) as child item of reference variant (for authors field) to access blog's author's reference media field on Blogs Page. However,the media items are not rendering on the page.
Please suggest what I am missing here. How to access multilist field inside author template when you are on blogs page?
Please check below screenshots-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your Reference Media field, point at a Sitecore item that contains an `Image` field, or is that pointing at a Media Item directly?

Comment: It is pointing to media item directly

Comment: I think issue is with the responsive image because I used token $name to check if the reference field is reaching the media images or not. $name is successfully rendering name of media images but responsive images are not showing.